# Tensorflow: reshape [N,H,W,C] to [N*C,H,W,1] for convolution per channel

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, convolution

What I would like to achieve is applying a 2D convolution with one filter that is applied across all channels. Note that I am not looking for a depthwise convolution, but really one filter. In order to do this, my plan was to reshape `[N,H,W,C]` to `[N*C,H,W,1]`, apply convolution, and then reshape back, so my output is `[N,H,W,C]` again.

```
_, self.h, self.w, self.c = inputs.shape
self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same')
x = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1,self.h,self.w,1])
x = self.conv(x)
x = tf.math.argmax(x, axis=3)
output = tf.reshape(x ,[-1,self.h,self.w,self.c])
```

However, while implementing this, I noticed that the output of the first reshape contains some kind of interleave between the channels or batch or something (image from ImageNet): [Before reshape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVycp.png), [After reshape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg64w.png). My intuition was that this might be because batch and channels are not adjacent in memory.

For this reason, I experimented by transposing the input first and then apply reshaping, convolution, reshaping and transposing back:

```
_, self.h, self.w, self.c = inputs.shape
self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', data_format="channels_first")
x_t = tf.transpose(inputs, [0,3,1,2]) # convert nhwc to nchw
x_t = tf.reshape(x_t, [-1,1,self.h,self.w])
x_t = self.conv(x_t)
x_t = tf.math.argmax(x_t, axis=1)
x_t = tf.reshape(x_t ,[-1,self.c,self.h,self.w])
output = tf.transpose(x_t, [0,2,3,1])
```

This indeed seems to work like I would expect, but is quite a slow approach.
I have a series of questions:

1. What is the exact reason for the interleaving pattern that I am experiencing?
2. Would there be a way to reshape my data without the need for the use of transpose? I am aware that I could perhaps go with `NCHW` data format everywhere, but as I am trying to build an implementation on an existing platform, I think changing data format will break other parts of the code.
3. Is there perhaps a completely different approach that I could take to apply convolution per channel? I have thought about using `unstack` or something, but that would require for loops, which is even more inefficient in my idea.

Thanks in advance

**edit**: I think I at least understand why the interleaving is happening. Let me try to explain by how I understand it, and format it as good as possible. The letters n,h,w,c here should help identifying to what a number belongs.

Suppose I have 16 numbers which are contiguous in memory:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

If they are shaped `NHWC: 2,2,2,2`

```
[n[h[w[c1,c2],
     w[c3,c4]], 
   h[w[c5,c6],
     w[c7,c8]]], 
 n[h[w[c9,c10],
     w[c11,c12]], 
   h[w[c13,c14],
     w[c15,c16]]]]
```

Then if they are reshaped to `NHWC: 4,2,2,1` and by keeping the underlying data contiguous, we get:

```
[n[h[w[c1],
     w[c2]], 
   h[w[c3],
     w[c4]]], 
 n[h[w[c5],
     w[c6]], 
   h[w[c7],
     w[c8]]], 
 n[h[w[c9],
     w[c10]], 
   h[w[c11],
     w[c12]]], 
 n[h[w[c13],
     w[c14]], 
   h[w[c15],
     w[c16]]]]
```

In this way channels get mixed up in the spatial dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, reshape doesn't work properly if you want to merge non consecutive dimensions so transposing is a good idea. However Conv2d expects the last dimension to be the input channels. In your case it is `self.w` but it is note likely what you want. You can change the reshape line to: `tf.reshape(x_t, [-1, self.h, self.w, 1])` like previously.

Comment: Indeed I seem to understand what is happening in terms of reshape.  I tried writing it out in the edit to my post.  The second version (with transpose) is actually having a convolution with `dataformat="channels_first"` to handle channels in the second dimension.

Comment: oh I didn't get it ok